# How to generate a Crystal Report from a list of parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-8.5, crystal-reports-server

My requirement is to generate a employee details report of multiple employees.Parameters for query will be employee number and a date range.

This is the record selection formula i'm using

```
{EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.LEAVE_START_DATE} in {?sDate} to {?eDate}

and
(
Stringvar Array strings := Split({?empNoList}, "_");

Numbervar Array numbers;
Redim numbers[Ubound(strings)];

Numbervar i;
for i := 1 to Ubound(strings) do (
numbers[i] := ToNumber(strings[i]);

if {EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO} = numbers[i] then 
(true;)
else 
(false;)

);
)
```

First i'm checking for the date.
Then i'm taking the employee list as a one string {?empNoList} eg: 5162_5468_5896_5236
and i'm splitting it to separate strings using "_" as the delimiter and assign those values again into a number array and using that value to filter the employee.

But this formula doesn't work.It gives the details of all the employees.
Is this a problem of the way i converted the string array or is there something wrong in the for loop of my code?

I used this code and tried assigning one employee number to the {?empNoList} and it worked.

```
if (ToNumber({?empNoList}) = {EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO}) then true else false
```

Please help me out with this.Thanks in advance!

Comment: please see my response to your previous question for the "proper" way you can achieve this

Comment: @LeeTickett : i think by previous question you meant this question byhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410798/how-to-split-a-string-and-make-an-array-of-integers-in-crystal-report

The problem with the split function was solved.I just didn't knew the proper way to use it. 

This is  the original problem.This is what i want to do with that array.

Can you please point me out if there's anything wrong with this formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
Stringvar Array strings := Split({?empNoList}, "_"); //Spliting and saving the string in a string array
Numbervar Array numbers;        //Creating a number array
Redim numbers[Ubound(strings)]; //Declaring number array size
Numbervar i;                       

//For loop to traverse through string and convert each into numbers and saving them in the numbers array
for i := 1 to Ubound(strings) do (      
    numbers[i] := ToNumber(strings[i]);
);

if({EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO} in numbers)  //If condition to check whether Employee number is in the numbers array
then
(true;)
else (false;)
```

It was a simple out of the box thinking ;)

Answer (score 0):

1) Convert your EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO to a string.
2) Then use the Like or In operator with {EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO} and {?empNoList}

Simply, search the string version EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO inside the bigger string {?empNoList}. You can avoid using the arrays.

Comment: Your idea is great.I tried it like this But it doesn't work either


  if ({?empNoList} like "*" & ToText ({EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO}) & "*") then true else false

Comment: * is the wildcard in crystal so: `{?empNoList} like "*" & ToText {EMP_LEAVE_REPORT_VIEW.EMP_NO} & "*"`

Comment: Yes i tried with the * somehow i missed it in the comment.Sorry about that.This didn't work either.