# Adding a / between numbers in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a date field that shows as CYYMMDD. To get rid of the century I have just subtracted 1000000 to show the date as YYMMDD ex. 150814.

Now I want to add / between the numbers to show as 15/08/14.

How do I do this in the formula?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need to subtract date to get your desired format of date. Just `right click` on the date and click `format`. And there take desired format with desired separators etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to be considered here.

1. Simply right click on the date field once you place the same in crystal report, you will get options to format data. You can choose whatsoever suits you.
2. In case you go by your approach for substracting the number..., you can convert the number into strong and then can play with it.
3. Posting the links for the second point help.[Split the number and modify in Crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410798/how-to-split-a-string-and-make-an-array-of-integers-in-crystal-report)