# How can I remove some decimal numbers to the field of Business partner aging (Summary report)?

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I want to remove decimal numbers to the filed (Total) of Business partner aging (Summary report) in crystal report

I tried to edit the formula but there is no luck, I want to have only two decimal numbers

Below is the codes

```
local stringvar amountstring;
if {PLD__ITEMS.F_119}='' then ' ' else 
(
    amountstring:={PLD__ITEMS.F_119};
    amountstring := replace(amountstring, "(", "-");
    amountstring := replace(amountstring, ")", "");
    amountstring := replace(amountstring, ")", "");
)
```

[image]

I need only two decimal numbers

Please anyone can help me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add one more line:
amountstring := ToText(cCur(amountstring),2,",");

2nd argument controls number of decimals.
3rd argument controls thousand separator.

Comment: I tried to add that line but I got error message, the string is non-numeric. Please see the second picture

Comment: Use IF THEN logic with isnumeric() function to apply the logic only to content that contains a number.

Comment: I used the logic of If isnumeric(amountstring) then, but it dislays nothing

Comment: Right, that's because it's not numeric, most likely because of the currency symbol ("USD" or "RWF")? You're going to need to split out the currency symbol to isolate the number. Check out this link on how to split the string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410798/how-to-split-a-string-and-make-an-array-of-integers-in-crystal-report

Comment: Splitting the string to remove the non-numeric data is an option if there are only a small number of distinct currency symbols.  If you have more than 2 or 3 different possible values for the currency symbol you may need to work with whomever handles you database design about splitting the data into two columns in the database.  Otherwise your formula is going to become very complex and difficult to manage.

Comment: I have to try to split the string into two columns in order to see if I can remove that decimal numbers. Currencies are only two